# "Authored by" field to be automatically filled

Tags: nodes

On every creation of a node or edit of a node I need the "Authored by" field to be automatically populated with the username of anyone saving changes.

any ideas how I can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate, do you really want the author to change every time a node is edited? If so: do you need to keep the name of the original author, or is it OK if the name of the last editor overwrites the original author?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear,
yes I want the author to change every time a node is edited.
no problem if it overwrites the original author.

Comment: Look like this has been asked and answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936968/change-node-author-automatically-drupal-7, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/43936/change-node-author-on-node-save-with-rules.

Comment: Thanks for the Links Adam,
would be quite useful if there is a solution in detail, I am very new Drupal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I think that a module like Rules (powerful and awesome as it is) is overkill for something relatively simple as this.

Looking at [node_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7), I see that the author is set by populating the author field with the username. I would create a custom module which implements [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7), and set the default value of the author name field to the name of the current user. That would look something like this (disclaimer: untested code!).

```
<?php

function MODULENAME_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Always set the username to the current user. An empty string means anonymous.
  global $user;
  $form['author']['name']['#default_value'] = !empty($user->name) ? $user->name : '';
}
```

An advantage of this solution is that the field is populated in advance with a default value, allowing user with sufficient permissions (eg. administrators) to override the author as they always can. It would be harder to do that in a rules-based approach which only kicks in after the form has been submitted.

---

*update:*

The topic starter mentions in another answer that he ended up with the following code:

```
function module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Always set the username to the current user. An empty string means anonymous.
  global $user;
  if ($form_id == 'content_type_node_form') {
    $form['author']['name']['#default_value'] = $user->name;
  }
}
```

Some feedback on this code:

- Of course, the if-statement makes sense if you only need this behavior in certain cases. You could even place the `global $user;` inside the if.
- I would recommend that you keep the `!empty($user->name) ? $user->name : ''` part, instead of simply using `$user->name`. It may be an edge case, but as you can see in [drupal_anonymous_user](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_anonymous_user/7), the global $user object does not necessarily contain a 'name' property. If, at some point in the future, this form would become available for anonymous users, they will end up with php notices on their screen.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to do this. You need to create a rule to respond to a node being updated, then add an action which sets the author value from the current user.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a bunch, It worked well and I simply did this(just a few changes from what you've written)

```
function module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Always set the username to the current user. An empty string means anonymous.
  global $user;
  if($form_id=='content_type_node_form'){
    $form['author']['name']['#default_value'] = $user->name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to implement this in any node form irrespective of Content type then we can use preg_match.

```
function change_author_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{

global $user;
// for all type of content node forms we can use preg_match
if (preg_match('/.*_node_form/',$form_id)) {
$form['author']['name']['#default_value'] = $user->name ;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should just happen when created, if Author and Date information are ticked in admin/structure/types/manage/[your_content_type], under display settings.

If you want something else, you can use the [token module](http://drupal.org/project/token) and use a token as default value ; again in the content type settings.

If you want it updated with every save, you have to use [hook_node_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) in a custom module, and set `$node->uid` to current user's ID (`global $user; $user->uid`).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question; the question says "populated with the username of anyone saving changes" By default, Drupal only sets the author when a node is created, but it doesn't update the author when the node is edited.

Comment: Hi rémy,
Thanks for the reply, but that is  done. My question is, how to automatically populate the username in the "Authored by field"