# How to change the author of a node after payment using the rules module?

Tags: commerce, rules

I would like to use the [rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to change the author of a node after payment.

Even though I have limited experience with the rules module, I am sure it is possible to do.

This is what I'm looking for:

1. Client pays for existing node.
2. Ownership of the node is transferred to that client.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Absolutely possible. [Learn the Rules framework](http://nodeone.se/en/learn-the-rules-framework)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a variation of the question "[Change node author on node save with rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/43936/change-node-author-on-node-save-with-rules)". And the accepted answer there (with the comment added to it) seems the answer to it.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: No, "Change node author on node save with rules" does not answer my question.